# bash: ./script.sh: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the script below which I run with from within a directory of images with ./checkres.sh * or even *.jpg, but it only works if there is a small number of files, less than 100 or so. Anything more and it stops with error "Argument list too long" and I have 100,000's of images to process.

I been looking all over the web for hours and tried dozens of different changes, using a while instead of a for loop and various other changes to variables but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help solve this mystery as I'm new to bash scripting and have run out of ideas.

```
#!/bin/bash
for img in "$@"
do

export height=`identify -format %h "$img"`
export width=`identify -format %w "$img"`
let ratio=$width/$height

echo Image "$img" = [ $width x $height ] = $ratio

if [ $ratio == 0 ]
then
    echo Portrait 0
    convert "$img" -geometry 600x800 -format jpeg -quality 80 "$img"
else
    echo Landscape 1
    convert "$img" -geometry 800x600 -format jpeg -quality 80 "$img"
fi
```

Comment: some errors here. You can check the basic ones in shellcheck.net

Comment: Won't it be better to use a directory nene as an argument? Then you could place terabytes of images in it and your script won't give errors.

Comment: As an aside -- don't use `.sh` extensions for scripts that define commands. Think about what happens if you were to rewrite it in Python -- would you want to either make everything that calls/invoke it to change to run `./checkres.py`, or have a Python script named with a `.sh` name? Just call it `checkres`, same as you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`.

Comment: ...on a different point: There's no need whatsoever to `export` your height or width values, and you could more efficiently check them both in a single `identify` command: `read width height < <(identify -format '%w %h\n'' "$img")`

Comment: regarding arg list length, this article explains quite well a few options (incl. the one proposed as answer by @CharlesDuffy.  I would avoid method #4 :)  http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060

Comment: I'd also consider `if (( ratio == 0 ))`; simpler and more readable. If you want to use `[ ]` for that test, you need to tweak it a bit to robust: `[ "$ratio" -eq 0 ]` would handle the corner cases better.

Comment: As another aside, `"$@"` is actually the default thing a for loop iterates over; just `for img; do` would have the same effect as `for img in "$@"; do`.

Comment: He needs more than quotes around `$ratio` to make that `[` test robust against various failures (though in this case since `let` isn't going to assign any non-numbers to `ratio` even the unquoted version is "safe" enough I think). To be safer he'd need to handle an error from `[` differently than a false return (for non-number values of `$ratio`).

Comment: @tgo, I haven't read that article in entirety, but its example `3a` is also buggy. One can't safely use `read` without `-r` with arbitrary names (as this will interpret backslash-escape sequences rather than treating them as literal) -- or, for that matter, without clearing IFS and using a NUL-delimited stream (to handle the really bizarre cases like filenames with newlines in their names). The lack of rigor is disturbing.

Comment: lol thanks for all the replies. hmm, maybe it needs a directory for argument like the poster said. I'm just trying to get it to run, what I want it to is echo all images greater than 800px wide, so I'm just using this to get started.

Comment: also, using the `$(command)` is more preferred as the backticks. Anyway, don't understand the down vote. it is an regular question. IMHO.

Comment: this works sort of but it does not echo the file name? It just print out the width of images larger than 800 px, but it runs through all the files I could not get the old script to work for some reason. #!/bin/bash
for file in *
 do
width=`identify -format '%w' "$file"`
if [ $width -gt 800 ]
then
     echo "Image: $filename is $width px wide"
fi
done
exit 0

Comment: I got it woo hoo! $filename should be $file. Hey thanks everyone :)

Comment: @ fedorqui nice http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change anything about your script; just change how you invoke it:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -exec ./checkres.sh '{}' +
```

This will put only as many filenames on each invocation as will fit, running the script more than once as necessary.

---

In fact -- unless you change the calling convention, you *can't* fix this bug by changing anything about your script, since the problem is happening while the shell is trying to start it!

However, there's another workaround -- instead of defining this as an external script, you could define it as a shell function (in your `~/.bashrc` or similar), which means it doesn't need to be started as an external command, meaning the operating system limits in question don't apply.

```
checkres() {
  for img; do
    ...
  done
}
checkres *.jpg
```

...is executed entirely within the shell, mooting any limits on the length of the command line which can be passed to an external command during its execution.

Comment: ./checkres.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @newbtard, oh -- think I found the cause of your syntax error; I had too many quotation marks in some code I gave in a comment (typos, *sigh*). `read width height < <(identify -format '%w %h\n' "$img")` is the corrected form.

Comment: You might as well do `for img in *.jpg` directly in the script. Otherwise, `checkres *.jpg` will have a huge overhead: globbing (which is long), and then all the arguments will need to be copied to be passed to `checkres` and then looped over. And this will have a huge overhead!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, I agree that the globbing is expensive (more expensive than letting `find` do it, for that matter, since the shell sorts glob results into collation order), but is the copying to/from argv really significant on modern hardware? I can't think of an instance where I've ever noticed it.

Comment: After writing my comment, I had a doubt too, and nearly deleted it. But I tried this: `mkdir gniourf; cd gniourf; touch {1..100000}; touch {100001..200000}; touch {200001..300000}` then: `time bash -c 'for i in *; do :; done'` which took 2.7s and `time bash -c 'f() { for i; do :; done; }; f *'` which took 4s.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, given as performance is going to be almost completely driven by the amount of time calling the `identify` command, I don't think that a few seconds difference over the course of several hundred thousand files is significant here. But that *is* a very good point, and I'm revising my mental model on account of same.

Comment: yep found that one and fixed it Charles Duffy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a directory argument:

```
for img in "$1"/*; do
```

Quoting correctly this way will ensure that your code can deal with directory names containing spaces.

Comment: thanks I'll have another try and post it up if I get it working ;)